# jQuery - UI autocomplete issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, getjson

Using [jQ UI Autocomplete with multiple values](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple)

My function looks like that

```
mailto_input.bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.getJSON( "core/search.php", {
            term: extractLast( request.term )
        }, response );
    },
    search: function(){
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 2 ) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    focus: function() {
        // prevent value inserted on focus
        return false;
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( "; " );
        return false;
    }
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is, to limit user to select only serverside data.  I mean, I want to add term into input box ONLY if there is any result from PHP side. Else, notify user that, there is no data in server like this term

For ex.

[image]

I want to prevent adding words like `sdsf` (in this case server responds like `[]`). In other words, add ONLY if there is at least 1 suggestion from serverside. Else stay as it was and notify user about issue.

Is that possible? How can I achieve this result?

Comment: You mean like the way stackoverflow does tags?

Comment: try looking at the stackoverflow api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a go at [Tokeninput](https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput). It does exactly what you are trying to do.

Also, here's the [demo](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) just to make sure it's what you want...

Comment: can't find what I need. It doesn't prevent when you type things like "gsfs"

Comment: While the user can type in "gsfs" they can't actually enter it as a tag. Only results returned by the PHP are turned into tags. When the user submits the form you can easily filter out non-tag entries.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way they do it is they exchange the tag for a span.

```
<div id="taginput">
    <span id="tags">
    <span>tagname</span>
    </span>
    <input type="text" id="tagtext"/>
</div>
```

You have to make it so the suggestions are added before as spans:

```
$('.suggestion_element_class').click(function() {
    textof = this.text();
    $('#tags').append('<span>' + textof + '</span>');
    $('#tagtext').val('');
});
```

Of course, you would have to get the suggestions first and everything.